# I want to create a login Activity as facebook have

Tags: android

I want to create a login Activity as facebook have, so how can I do this and how to communicate with server to verify these details ?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is FireBase or some online database thats all, after that you will save login details there will check it and verify the users, its nothing special.

Answer (score 0):

About the user interface (UI), you should spend more time to work with XML, about how to design a good UI for your application (you can watch tutorial videos on youtube).

About the communication between your device and server, you shoud get used to work with "web services". This knowledge you can easily find tutorials and demonstration on youtube also (Keyword: "web service android", "android login using php & mysql"). Or use FireBase instead of php & mysql.

Hope you guy learn well :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too generic, so you can only have a generic response:

1. Think about **UI** you'd like to have for customers login.
2. Write **XML layout** according UI and show it in the login activity.
3. Create a database on remote server with **Users Table** to store credentials.
4. Use a **server side language** (maybe php?) or any **online tool** to implement login api, which will get credentials from app and store them in database.
5. Implement in the activity the logic for **local credential validation** and to **send credentials** (crypted is better) to backend api when login button is pressed.

Good luck ;)